# Ford has proper fuel pressure and spark but won't start

Tags: ford, starting, expedition

My '97 Ford Expedition turns over but won't start. I have replaced the fuel pump and filter with no results. Fuel is hitting the rail at pressure. I checked the spark with a noid light, and it's getting spark. I pulled the crank position sensor wire and re-attached and it started one time but went right back to cranking over but not starting after a short drive.

Answer (score 4):

If you found it restarted once by removing the wiring to the sensor, your issue is going to lie either with the sensor, the wiring, or the connection.

- Check the wiring for breaks
- Check the plug for corrosion or damage, clean or replace if needed
- If all else fails, replace the sensor.